# Android Q - How to add nested folder to Uri

Tags: android, uri, updates, storage-access-framework

With `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` I picked subfolder `"abc/bumbum"` in `"Downloads"` folder. Resulted uri is :

```
content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/tree/msd%3A127
```

Under this uri I have now read and write permissions.

"bumbum" folder contains another subfolder "test".

How can I update returned uri with subfolder 'test' if I want create file in "test" folder ?

Answer (score 1):

```
String contentScheme = "content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/tree/msd%3A127";

String folder = "test";

if (createDirectory(contentScheme, folder))
  {
  ;
  }


private boolean createDirectory ( String contentScheme, String folderName ) {

DocumentFile documentDir = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(context, Uri.parse(contentScheme));

if ( documentDir==null )
{
Toast.makeText( context, "documentDir==null\n\n" + contentScheme, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

return false;
}

DocumentFile folder = documentDir.createDirectory(folderName);

if ( folder==null )
{
Toast.makeText( context, "documentsubDir==null\n\n" + folderName + "\n\n" + contentScheme, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

return false;
}

Toast.makeText( context, "created\n\n" + folder.getName() + "\n\n" + contentScheme, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

return true;
```

}